# Amazon Web Services DynamoDB Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using [Dynamoose](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose) to handle DynamoDB requests and actions in Node.js.

I'm getting this error when I try to get a record tho. (email is a variable defined earlier)

```
User.get({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
    // if there are any errors, return the error
    if (err)
        return done(err);
}
```

err is returning

> ValidationException: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: [object Object]

Any ideas why I would be getting this error?

Comment: what are the partition and sort keys of the table?

Comment: @ketan Not totally sure. I fixed it by doing scan instead of get. I don't believe I specially set partition and sort keys.

Comment: that's the problem then.. you need to set `email` as the partition-key of your table, and then the above `get` command should work

Comment: @ketan Ok now what exactly do partition keys do? And what will be the differences in scan vs partition key and get? Is there a speed difference? Overall what are the differences and which is better. Also feel free to make an answer and I will up vote and accept if it works when I test it.